# Avoid space when using mintinline wrapped in a new command

Tags: minted

I want to wrap `mintinline` into a new command `\cc` but it produces an additional whitespace when using it:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{minted}

\newcommand{\cc}[1]{{\mintinline{latex}{#1}}}

\begin{document}

{\mintinline{latex}{\mycommand{argument}}}

\cc{\mycommand{argument}}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: output]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The package documentation mentions `\newmintinline`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{minted}

\newmintinline[cc]{latex}{}

\begin{document}

\mintinline{latex}{\mycommand{argument}}

\cc{\mycommand{argument}}

\end{document}
```

[image]